# Arithmetic overflow error converting float to data type numeric

Tags: java, mysql, database, struts2, bigdecimal

I have a column in MySQL db and its data type is `decimal(6,6)`. Now in order to store data in that column what data type i should take in Java? Now I tried using `double`, `float`, and `BigDecimal`, nothing works for me?

Comment: Can you elaborate on how it doesn't work? Perhaps supply some code?

Comment: NOTE: In MySQL DECIMAL(6,6) means six digits maximum, with six digits to the right of the point. Are you sure this is what you need?

Comment: Yes, I am sure about that. What is the minimum digit , I need to supply for insertion in DECIMAL(6,6)?

Comment: How do you do conversion? Post some code.

Comment: You need to clarify the version of db.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

According to the MySQL official reference (Connector/J JDBC Reference) the `DECIMAL` type is mapped to `java.math.BigDecimal`. Also see the [25.4.4.3. Java, JDBC and MySQL Types](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/es/connector-j-reference-type-conversions.html).